# One primary partition left: Root or home?

Tags: windows-7, linux, partitioning, root, crunchbang

I have Windows running on two partitions of my computer. I am now planning to install crunchbang on the left space. Hence I have one primary and two logical partitions left if I want to have root, home and swap. I would think I'd place the extended partition at the end.
But which partition is more important to be primary? Root or home? My guess would be:

/     --> primary

/home --> logical

swap  --> logical

Or completely different?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: On my Ubuntu GNU/Linux system, I just have my root and swap both stored on logical partitions (FYI, rather than having a home "partition", I just have a home directory in my root partition). I have yet to notice any problems on my setup.

Comment: Thanks! But: No separate home - for a certain reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no difference, AFAIK. If it helps you, my current HDD layout looks very similar to yours, and in my case I indeed have / as the primary partition and /home and swap as logical partitions within the extended partition. It looks like this:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x52305230

Device    Boot     Start       End    Blocks  Id System
/dev/sda1         208896  82223103  41007104   7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2 *     82223104 205697023  61736960  83 Linux
/dev/sda3      205697024 488396799 141349888   5 Extended
/dev/sda5      205699072 480008191 137154560  83 Linux
/dev/sda6      480010240 488396799   4193280  82 Linux swap / Solaris

$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  39.1G  0 part /mnt/win
├─sda2   8:2    0  58.9G  0 part /
├─sda3   8:3    0     1K  0 part
├─sda5   8:5    0 130.8G  0 part /home
└─sda6   8:6    0     4G  0 part [SWAP]
```

NOTE: You may have noticed that I'm only using three primary partitions (Win, root and extended) instead of four; that's because there's another very small (100 MiB) hidden primary partition at the beginning of the disk that doesn't show there. Just testing stuff, I'll get rid of it next time I format the box, but it doesn't invalidate my point.

Comment: Actually, your `fdisk` output clearly indicates you're using three primary partitions, period. (One of those, `/dev/sda3`, is your extended partition.) The "very small... hidden primary partition" isn't a partition; it's unpartitioned space. That said, you're right that the choice of primary vs. logical partitions won't have any performance implications.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I meant, unpartitioned space. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to misunderstand primary, extended, and logical partitions. An MBR disk supports up to four primary partitions. As that's limiting, one of these partitions may be configured as an extended partition, which can hold an *arbitrarily large number* of logical partitions. Thus, your belief that you have "...two logical partitions left..." is in error; if you've got unused space within your extended partition, you can create as many logical partitions as will fit in your unused space.

Before you start planning this out, though, be aware that MBR is on the way out. If your computer came with OS X or Windows 8 pre-installed, and perhaps if it came with Windows 7 from the last year or so of its reign, your computer probably boots with an EFI instead of a BIOS and uses GPT rather than MBR partitions. GPT doesn't distinguish between primary, extended, and logical partitions, and GPT supports up to 128 partitions by default. Thus, if you're using a recent computer, you might not need to worry about this ancient distinction. In fact, it's possible to use GPT on even older computers, but the advantages of doing so are slim.

As to a `/home` partition, that's a matter of opinion. Mine is that `/home` partitions are advisable on any but the smallest installations, because they help isolate user data from system data. This can simplify certain types of upgrades and system backups

Comment: "Two logical partitions left" might have been an ambiguous phrase. I know that I can have more than two logical partitions, but if I am planning to add three partitions with only two primary partitions left, this was the configuration "left for me" (The computer in question is from 2008).